# Error Could not resolve dependency: redux-react-session

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, redux

I need to install this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-react-session

installing it with npm `npm i redux-react-session` shows this error:

```
PS C:\Users\michael\Desktop\login and signup\client> npm i redux-react-session
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from redux-react-session@2.6.1
npm ERR! node_modules/redux-react-session
npm ERR!   redux-react-session@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.0",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.8.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "antd": "^4.20.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^5.1.5",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when installing npm packages?
There are two solutions to resolve this issue. Let us look at each of those in detail.

Solution 1: Ignore the peerDependencies
The easiest way to fix the issue is to pass an additional parameter –legacy-peer-deps to npm install. The `--legacy-peer-deps` tells the npm to ignore the peer dependencies and continue the installation of the package.

Try the below command to install the dependencies for your project.

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

You can also set this permanently by adding this into a configuration by running the below command.

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

Note: In this solution, the peer dependencies will not be installed by default, even if you are using the latest version of NPM.

Solution 2: `Using –force`
The other solution is to use the --force flag. The -f or --force argument will force npm to fetch remote resources even if a local copy exists on disk.

Step 1: Delete the current node_modules. You can remove it by using the below command.

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Step 2: Remove the package-lock.json by running the below command

```
rm package-lock.json
```

Step 3: Clear the npm cache and perform the clean installation with --force flag as shown below.

```
npm cache clean --force

npm install --force
```

By performing the above steps, you should resolve the issue successfully.

Comment: `npm i redux-react-session --save --legacy-peer-deps` seems to work for me. Thanks!